# Overview for Deep Learning Networks

Tags: deep-learning

I am fairly new to Deep Learning and get quite overwhelmed by the many different Nets and their field of application. Thus, I want to know if there is some kind of overview which kind of different networks exist, what there key-features are and what kind of purpose they have.

For example I know abut LeNet, ConvNet, AlexNet - and somehow they are the same but still differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two types of neural networks, **supervised** and **unsupervised** learning. Both need a training set to "learn". Imagine **training set** as a **massive book** where you can **learn** specific information. In supervised learning, the book is supplied with answer key but without the solution manual, in contrast, unsupervised learning comes without answer key or solution manual. But the goal is the same, which is that to find patterns between the questions and answers (supervised learning) and questions (unsupervised learning).

Now we have differentiate between those two, we can go into the models. Let's discuss about supervised learning, which basically has 3 main models:

- artificial neural network (ANN)
- convolutional neural network (CNN)
- recurrent neural network (RNN)

ANN is the simplest of all three. I believe that you have understand it, so we can move forward to CNN.

Basically in CNN all you have to do is to convolve our input with feature detectors. Feature detectors are matrices which have the dimension of (row,column,depth(number of feature detectors). The goal of convolving our input is to extract informations related to spatial data. Let's say you want to distinguish between cats and dogs. Cats have whiskers but dogs does not. Cats also have different eyes than dogs and so on. But the downside is, the more convolution layers will result in slower computation time. To mitigate that, we do some kind of processing called **pooling** or **downsampling**. Basically, this reduce the size of feature detectors while minimizing lost features or information. Then the next step would be **flattening** or squashing all those 3d matrix into (n,1) dimension so you can input it into ANN. Then the next step is self explanatory, which is normal ANN. Because CNN is inherently able to detect certain features, it mostly(maybe always) used for classification, for example image classification, time series classification, or maybe even video classification. For a crash course in CNN, check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAICT4Al5Ow&index=11&list=PL2-dafEMk2A7YdKv4XfKpfbTH5z6rEEj3) by Siraj Raval. He's my favourite youtuber of all time!

Arguably the most sophisticated of all three, **RNN** is bestly described as neural networks that have "memory" by introducing "loops" within them which allow information to persist. Why is this important? As you are reading this, your brain use previous memory to comprehend all of this information. You don't seem to rethink everything from scratch again and this is what traditional neural networks do, which is to forget everything and re-learn again. But native RNN aren't effective so when people talk about **RNN** they mostly refer to **LSTM** which stands for Long Short-Term Memory. If that seems confusing to you, [Cristopher Olah](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) will give you in depth explanation in a very simple way. I advice you to check out his link for complete understanding about how **RNN**, especially **LSTM** variant

As for unsupervised learning, I'm so sorry that I haven't got the time to learn them, so this is the best I can do. Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

They are the same type of Networks. Convolutional Neural Networks. The problem with the overview is that as soon as you post something it is already outdated. Most of the networks you describe are already old, even though they are only a few years old.

Nevertheless you can take a look at the networks supplied by caffe (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models).

In my personal view the most important concepts in deep Learning are recurrent networks (https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/), residual connections, inception blocks (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07261). The rest are largely theoretical concepts, which would not fit in a stack overflow answer.